# Why do we use left and right node pointers within the node structure?

Tags: c++

This is the class binary search tree

Why do we create nodes left and right pointer within the node structure which will again have 3 attributes?  Why not just use an `int`?

```
class bst
{
 struct node
    {
        int key;
        node *left;
        node *right;
    };
    node *root;
};
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Without *two* pointers, it wouldn't really be a *binary* tree.

Comment: it could be int pointers.

Comment: The pointers *have* to point to other objects of *node* type. That's how a tree works.

Comment: Draw a binary tree.  Every node can have a left and a right branch.

Comment: Those pointers each represent a branch in the tree. You could use the index of the node representing the branch in another list of all known nodes, but often that leads to unnecessary overhead.

Comment: so it means the node isn't exactly a data type. we just name it according to the structure.

Comment: `node` is a data type, but you could have named it anything. `branch` may be a more descriptive name for a tree's node structure, but because a tree is a type of graph structure and the generalized graph structure calls them `node`, the name `node` has stuck.

Comment: If you use an array for allocation, instead of dynamic memory, you can have `left` and `right` as integer indices to the appropriate nodes.

Comment: The point is, sooner or later you need a structure like `node` to describe the rest of the tree. Nodes connect to nodes which are connected to still more nodes until you get to what's called a leaf: A node with no attached nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following your comment, I believe I understand your confusion.

The reason the `node` structure contains pointers to other `node` structures and not to `int` is to allow the tree to have multiple levels.

Each node has a value, and can have one or two children nodes, but each of those nodes can have its own children.

BST - a binary search tree, can grow as large as your computer memory will allow, depending on how much data you want to store in it.

Look at this image (taken from Wikipedia):

[image: Binary Search Tree]

If you used pointers to `int` you could only store 8, 3, and 10, but would have no way to store 1, 6, 14 and the rest of the values.

But with every node containing a value **and** a pointer to other nodes you can chain as many of them as you need.

Comment: wow... now i know, its for chain reaction kind of thing

Comment: Nice inuiting Lev!